# controller not actualize string interpolation

Tags: angular, string-interpolation

I got a problem

My hellow.component.html is:

```
<form>
    <input ng-model="hello" type="text">
</form>
<p>{{hello}}</p>
```

and hellow.component.ts is:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hellow',
  templateUrl: './hellow.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hellow.component.css']
})
export class HellowComponent implements OnInit {

  hello:string ='';
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Can you answer
If I write something in input, {{hello}} string interpolation is not actualized by controller.
Can you help me with this matter?

also tried with:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="hello" type="text">
```

Thank you, a lot.

Comment: Check your console...

Comment: Try setting the name attribute to "hello" on the input box as well as the [(ngModel)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `ngModel` within  tags, you'll also need to supply a name attribute so that the control can be registered with the parent form under that name.
Try this.

```
 <form>
        <input name="hello" [(ngModel)]="hello" type="text">
  </form>
    <p>{{hello}}</p>
```

Comment: That's work!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you import `FormsModule`?

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: Yes, I did that. Also add 'FormsModule' in imports array of @NgModule decorator

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved
I forgot to add `name="hello"` attribute in input tag
Thanks a lot for help!